# How can I stabilize KafkaConsumer (0.10.0.0) before poll loop? (getting 'unkown' offsets)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a simple 4-partition topic, lowercaseStrings.  I create a KafkaConsumer and subscribe to the topic like so:

```
  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[Array[Byte], V](
    (Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> host,
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "false",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
      "group.id" -> "mygroup"
    )),
    new ByteArrayDeserializer,
    new StringDeserializer
  )
  consumer.subscribe(List(topic))
```

At this point I pre-populate the topic with 1 million strings and fire up this consumer's poll loop.  I'll poll all 1M successfully and commit them manually but when I examine the group stats I sometimes see things like this:

```
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
speed                          lowercaseStrings               0          unknown         250000          unknown         consumer-1_/192.168.99.1
speed                          lowercaseStrings               1          unknown         250000          unknown         consumer-1_/192.168.99.1
speed                          lowercaseStrings               2          unknown         250000          unknown         consumer-1_/192.168.99.1
speed                          lowercaseStrings               3          unknown         250000          unknown         consumer-1_/192.168.99.1
```

That's not good.  This isn't consistent, and I sometimes see a mix of known/unknown offsets, often with huge lag.

I even tried a "dummy", no-data poll before my main poll loop to try to force the rebalance to settle, like this (after consumer.subscribe):

```
  consumer.pause(consumer.assignment)
  consumer.poll(0)
  consumer.resume(consumer.assignment)
```

After this I can see something meaningful if I print consumer.assignment, but the offset results are unchanged.

I'm wondering if its trying to poll before the consumer is "settled" or something, leading to the inconsistent results.

How can I get consistent/correct behavior?

Comment: What tool do you use to check the offsets?

Comment: You called your group "mygroup" while your stats showing a groupname "speed". Is it a misstake or did you just query the stats of the wrong group? Can you further tell us something about your setup? Do you store your offsets to zookeeper or to kafka? How do you commit the offsets?

Comment: Sorry mistake in the example code.  mygroup is the group. Offsets stored in kafka.  I'm using ConsumerGroupCommand to get group info.